# Is there a mechanism for a register bit value to control some other attribute?

Tags: origen-sdk

Looking for something to change a mode or parameter based on value of register bit(s).  Something like an 'on_modify' for a bit collection.  Does that already exist?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, though the reverse (update a parameter and have it reflected in the register) is supported if that is any good to you.

See the last example about binding register bits to a live parameter here - http://origen-sdk.org/origen//guides/models/parameters/#Live_Updating_Parameters

Adding some new functionality to bit collection so that it supported something like the following API should not be too difficult:

```
my_reg.my_bits.on_data_changed do |data|
  do_something.based_on(data)
end
```

The `on_data_changed` method would just store the given block in the bit collection instance and then trigger it whenever the `write` method is called.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  I'll take a look at your example but maybe sounds like I will need to implement the on_data_changed to meet my needs.